# How to print fields in page.tpl.php

Tags: theming, entities

I need to print a particular field I have added to my basic page content type, I want this field to appear on every page, the name of my field is 'field_featured_image' I have tried a few different methods and nothing seems to output my field.

I thought it would be as simple as this, however no such luck

Comment: Does this field belong to a particular content type? How would Drupal know which field value of which node to output, if it would be to be printed on every page? What would the criterion be, eg. a particular node ID?

Comment: Node templates should have a $node variable that you can use to render the fields. Can you give examples of the code you have tried that isn't working?